# Running Program with Emulator, "Local SDK Path not set!"

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

When I run my program with the emulator on Android Studio I get an error as follows

> Local SDK Path Not Set

When i checked this in my project structure my SDK path is

```
C:\Android\sdk
```

and this is the same in my SDK Manager. I'm new to Android Studio and am curious of why my emulator loads, but does not run my program.Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: It just happened to me. Upgrading Android Studio to the latest beta solved it.

Comment: happening to me as well. I have the sdk and the path is set. But it keeps telling me the sdk path is not set.

Answer (score 10):

In the menu Run > Edit Configurations if you have the deployment target as "Emulator" with no preferred device selected you may run into this issue. Instead, choose deployment target as "Open Select Deployment Target Dialog". This will let you select from any installed emulator or a device connected by USB. Make sure to hit "Apply" before closing the Edit Configurations menu.

[Edit Configurations with Emulator but no Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAjEC.png)

[Edit Configurations with Open Select Deployment Target Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPxSC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same problem after synchronizing gradle. All I had to do was turn the emulator off and on again to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to the internet (so Android Studio and Gradle can actually complete their tasks) and perform a Gradle sync ('Sync Project with Gradle Files').

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the error after gradle sync, then set your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

On macOS, once you know the location of the android SDK, open a terminal window and enter the following:

```
export ANDROID_HOME={YOUR_PATH}

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

source ~/.bash_profile
```